# PHP How cURL/FOpen Stop at Certain Characters

Tags: php, curl, fopen

Is there a way for PHP CURL functions to get the contents of the website, but stopped on the characters that we just ask. I think this sort of buffer.

so the script did not call the overall page

So schemes like this:

```
: curl execution
<html>
->
->
->
-> Title Detected
: curl close
->
->
->
->
</ html>
```

Please this is not a DOM problem. But how to curl stops when it finds that we ask.
this is my code :

```
function curl_download($Url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

If cURL can't handle this problem, how about fopen? and do you have an example?
Thanks before.Also please give me your example code for me,, thanks

Comment: As I knew, curl can't do this work but fopen might be ok, coz you can use read to filter stream on fopen.

Comment: can you give me an example with fopen method. thanks

Comment: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a *very simple* example using [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/fsockopen).  Extend it to fit your needs.

```
$host = 'www.site.com';
$port = 80;

$sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$sock) {
    die("Failed to connect.  $errno: $errstr");
}

// write http request to socket:
$request = "GET /file.html HTTP/1.0\r\n"
          ."Host: $host\r\n"
          ."User-Agent: some-user-agent\r\n"
          ."Connection: close\r\n"
          ."\r\n";

fwrite($sock, $request);

$buffer = '';  // buffer for storing response

while (!feof($sock)) {
    $buffer .= fgets($sock, 1024); // read 1024 bytes from socket, append to buffer

    if (strpos($buffer, '</title>') !== false)) { // title was found
        fclose($sock);
        break;
    }
}
```

So we connect to the HTTP server on the remote host, issue a simple HTTP/1.0 request, and read the response 1024 bytes at a time until the closing title tag is detected.  Once it is found, the connection is closed.

Note, even though we didn't read the entire response from the socket, the underlying system (PHP and the OS socket layer) may have read more (or possibly all depending on size) of the response.  In either case, you did prevent PHP from reading most of the response.  If the pages are very big, closing the socket early will likely prevent a bulk of the data from actually ever being received.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can parse the DOM with CURL

I advise you to use the string function like strstr, strtok...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: The problem is not at the string function like strstr,etc